# Theme JS is available but theme CSS isn't

Tags: functions, css, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

In `functions.php` I used the following code to enqueue assets, but for some reason all CSS is ignored (JS isn't ingonred):

```
function my_theme_enqueue_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'behavior', get_theme_file_uri( 'behavior.js' ), array(), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_assets' );
```

What's bad with the above code?

Comment: In your function, add the following line: `error_log( 'Parent Theme Style sheet is: ' . get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' ) );` Then look for that line in the `debug.log` located in `./wp-content/`. That will tell you if the correct link is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me best to separate styles, from scripts and other assets. This worked:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_parent_theme_file_uri() . 'style.css' );
}
add_action( 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 'wp_enqueue_styles' );

function my_theme_enqueue_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'behavior', get_theme_file_uri( 'behavior.js' ), array(), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_assets' );
```

Comment: While the separation of concerns is fine, use of `get_template_directory_uri()` for the parent style is outdated because of problems that they caused with same files names. So, for example, you cannot have `style.css` in the child theme as well. Every file has to be unique between both parent and child theme. That's why the WP Team created these new functions. There is a good explanation [here](https://bravokeyl.com/get-theme-file-uri-and-get-theme-file-path/)

Comment: The two separate functions in the question caused the site to lack styling. You are more than welcome to write an answer that will show where I was wrong.

Comment: Did you follow my suggestion in the comment I made to your question? Because that will tell you if the proper URL is being used.

Comment: No, I don't know what URL you mean to. I load the parent theme CSS, the child theme CSS and the pagebuilder (Elementor) CSS. I don't know what URLs take part in this, I don't to load a specific style, rather, all stylesheets available.

Comment: I've edited the answer @Cedon

Comment: And it still works?

Comment: Yes, the test site is working fine, it seems. All styling is in place and not just part of it.

Comment: @Cedon `style.css` is necessary for a child theme. You should need to separate style and scripts. Not every file between parent and child need to be unique, both `functions.php` and `style.css` are combined upon load. [See handbook for further clarification](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#2-create-a-stylesheet-style-css)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I know that. I just used style.css as an example. Bravokeyl uses script.js in his explanation that I linked to. The point is using the old functions required 100% unique names or else you had to dequeue the parent file and then enqueue the child one. These new functions negate the need for that.